# Get list of facets with Algolia PHP API

Tags: php, api, algolia

I need to get a list of all facets from an index with the Algolia PHP API but can't seem to find a method that supports this [kind of query](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/search/).

Is this possible with the current Algolia PHP API?

So, basically a list of the highlighted words:

[image]

Comment: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/search/ says that it will return a list of facets in the results. And there is an example of running the method using PHP. Have I missed something in relation to your question? What actual problem are you facing here? Have you tried to write any code?

Comment: @ADyson I would not have asked without trying first. The thing is, I have no query string I want to search for – I just need the available facets after they have been "grouped". I do get a list of all items in the index, but that's not what I need.

Comment: Ok I see. I admit I don't know this Algolia product so I don't really understand the data structure. I don't know what you mean by "grouped" in this context. But I also saw https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/backend-search/how-to/faceting/#retrieving-facets which implies you can search an index without specifying a search string, but return a list of all facets. In particular I was thinking of the example `index.search({
  facets: ['*']
});` - obvious that's in a different language, probably JavaScript, but I guess you could write the equivalent in PHP

Comment: @ADyson Yes, this logic applies to instantsearch.js, which is for the output in the frontend. My question was targeting the PHP equivalent via their API. But there does not seem to be a method for this kind of call.

Comment: Well I would assume that, if it's possible to write a HTTP call to do that query, then it's possible to write some PHP which would make that call, even if the current PHP code provided in their client library doesn't actually expose it. What I mean is, if it doesn't exist, you could always make your own

Comment: But I would guess that, since the search docs say "an empty query can be used to fetch all records" that the PHP equivalent of that JS call might be something like `$index->search("", [  'facets' => "*"]);` . Obviously  I can't execute that and I haven't checked the syntax, but I assume you get the idea

Comment: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/facets/ documents the parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option 1

Given that you're using PHP and thus are on the backend side of things, you can use the following:

```php
$settings = $index->getSettings();
```

You then get the facets in `$settings['attributesForFaceting']`.

To be able to call `getSettings` you need to initialize your API client with an API key that has the `settings` ACL set.
So either use your Admin API key, or a specific key you create in your dashboard for that purpose.

## Option 2

Having the `setting` ACL set on your API key is generally not appropriate on a frontend search app.

So for a frontend implementation (which is apparently not your case) the `search` function is what you need; it's OK to provide an empty search string, and you can tweak the query to improve response time & size:

```php
$response = $index->search('', [
  'attributesToRetrieve' => ['objectID'], // don't retrieve full objects
  'hitsPerPage' => 0, // send back an empty page of results anyway
  'facets' => '*' // ask for all facets,
  'responseFields' => 'facets' // limit JSON response to `facets`
]);
```

Once you get the response for that query, you'll get the list of facets with:

```php
$facets = array_keys($response['facets']);
```

Note the one **caveat** of this method though: if your index is quite large, then the response might not contain all facets values.
The reason for that is that a search engine like Algolia is designed to be **relevant** while being fast, as opposed to databases which are designed to be **exhaustive** while being fast. As a result, when an index is too large to be "browsed" within a certain amount of time, Algolia will time out and send back the results it got (NB. that's a basic view of how things happen).

## Option 3

I don't have the details of your project, but have you looked into [instantsearch.js](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/what-is-instantsearch/js/)?
This is the go-to lib (or one of its variants) to build a search experience with Algolia. Everything done on the front-end, with direct calls to their API servers, that's the best way to get a snappy search experience :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We do use instantsearch.js for the frontend, but the customer wants to specify the variants of filters via the TYPO3 backend, thus we needed to get a list of all facets. We ended up with this PHP query: `$facetsResult = $index->search('', ['facets' => ['*']]);
$facets = $facetsResult['facets'];`

Comment: @Andreas Okay, be careful about the caveat I mentioned then if their index grows too big!